# How do I avoid having to unlock twice when using xtrlock?

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

I've installed `xtrlock` on Ubuntu 12.04. I run it manually from the command line in the evening, when I want to lock the keyboard/mouse but still leave the screen active. When I come back the next morning and enter my password, the screen immediately goes black, and then I'm presented with the normal Ubuntu unlock screen.  How can I prevent the normal lock from happening after I've unlocked xtrlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu-Gnome you can disable the password request on Settings/Brightness, by removing the flag from "Lock" and/or from "Lock the screen after resuming from suspend"...try and check if there's something similar on Unity!

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to do that, as the timed lock is nice in case I forget, but it certainly answers the question and clarifies things.